# Why condition @if in laravel blade not working? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

If my code is like this :

```
<ul class="test">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        @if($loop->first)
            $category_id = $category->id
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

There exist error :

> Undefined variable: category_id (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\resources\views\front.blade.php)

If my code is like this :

```
<ul class="test">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        @php
        if($loop->first)
            $category_id = $category->id
        @endphp
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

I works

Why the first way does not work?

Comment: Define the category_id variable before looping it and then assign a variable in looping..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are trying to assign a variable in Blade view. Here are ways to assign variables in Blade template.

```
{{--*/ $category_id = $category->id /*--}}
<?php $category_id = $category->id ?>
@php $category_id = $category->id @endphp
```

The space between `@if()` and `@endif` is simply html. That's why you use curly braces to echo values `{{ $value }}`